# Progress bar during uploading image in Android

Tags: android-studio, image-uploading, android-progressbar

Need real help here guys.
How can i show a progress bar inside imageView untill the image gets properly uploaded and show RETRY option inside the imageview in case of failure or error. Just like it happens during image uploading in Whatsapp.

Any lead would be helpful.